# How to safely parallel the for-loop with memcpy inside

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

I am developing a originally serial code in KSVD package to support OpenMP. The original code, which serves like im2col in MATLAB and extracts patches from the image, is shown as follows:

```
/* n stands for the size of an image, sz stands for the patch size to extract */
int blocknum = 0;
for (k=0; k<=n[2]-sz[2]; k+=1) {
    for (j=0; j<=n[1]-sz[1]; j+=1) {
        for (i=0; i<=n[0]-sz[0]; i+=1) {

            /* copy single block */
            for (m=0; m<sz[2]; m++) {
                for (l=0; l<sz[1]; l++) {
                    memcpy(b + blocknum*sz[0]*sz[1]*sz[2] + m*sz[0]*sz[1] + l*sz[0], x+(k+m)*n[0]*n[1]+(j+l)*n[0]+i, sz[0]*sizeof(double));
                }
            }
            blocknum ++;
        }
    }
}
```

While, I would like to make it parallel by replacing the incremental blocknum with an indexing variable blockid.

```
/* n stands for the size of an image, sz stands for the patch size to extract */
int blockid3, blockid2, blockid;
for (k=0; k<=n[2]-sz[2]; k+=1) {
    blockid3 = k * (n[1]-sz[1]+1) * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (j=0; j<=n[1]-sz[1]; j+=1) {
        blockid2 = j * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);
        for (i=0; i<=n[0]-sz[0]; i+=1) {
            blockid = i + blockid2 + blockid3;

            /* copy single block */
            for (m=0; m<sz[2]; m++) {
                for (l=0; l<sz[1]; l++) {
                    memcpy(b + blockid*sz[0]*sz[1]*sz[2] + m*sz[0]*sz[1] + l*sz[0], x+(k+m)*n[0]*n[1]+(j+l)*n[0]+i, sz[0]*sizeof(double));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then running leads me to fatal segmentation error. I do not know why (according to the stack trace, it seems related to safe threading). Because I thought parallel threads should not visit the same address once. Am I supposed to set some properties of variables, i.e. static or shared or private? Here is the stack trace:

```
Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f9bcaa695de    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00210398 _ZN2fl4diag15stacktrace_base7capt
ureERKNS0_14thread_contextEm+000158
[  1] 0x00007f9bcaa6b62d    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00218669
[  2] 0x00007f9bcaa6b8f5    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00219381 _ZN2fl4diag13terminate_logEPKcRKN
S0_14thread_contextEb+000165
[  3] 0x00007f9bc9a714f5   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00447733 _ZN2fl4diag13terminate_logEPKcPK8
ucontextb+000085
[  4] 0x00007f9bc9a6e5b4   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00435636
[  5] 0x00007f9bc9a6f333   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00439091
[  6] 0x00007f9bc9a6f4c7   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00439495
[  7] 0x00007f9bc9a7085f   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00444511
[  8] 0x00007f9bc9a70a15   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00444949
[  9] 0x00007f9bc89f0cb0              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00064688
[ 10] 0x00007f9bc876cb8e                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01346446
[ 11] 0x00007f9b88238bb8 /home/peiyun/schmax3.0/test_im2col/mex_im2colstep.mexa64+00003000
[ 12] 0x00007f9bcb004eea    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.3//libgomp.so+00032490
[ 13] 0x00007f9bc89e8e9a              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00032410
[ 14] 0x00007f9bc87164bd                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00992445 clone+000109
```

By the way, if they are writing to different addresses, are there any race conditions regarding memcpy inside the omp for-loop?

Comment: It is impossible to analyze this, there are too many loops and variables with unknown values, but as a start, have you tried adding the single `#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)` before the first `for` instead, without rewriting everything? If you are never accessing the same memory block, it should be safe.

Comment: Could you elaborate on KSVD ? Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-SVD ?

Comment: You tagged this as C++. To me, usage of `memcpy()` in a C++ source has a lousy smell. I agree with Vinces's comment and suggest retagging this as C.

Comment: I agree with @Vince and @kebs. As a side note, do the `src` and `dst` areas overlap? If so you should use `memmove()`.

Comment: @Vince, I am sorry and I have edited, thanks for your advice!

Comment: @kebs, K-SVD is what the wiki indicates. This code is from its toolbox.

Comment: @TimothyBrown, I use the variable blockid to make sure that they do not overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple data races in your code, namely:

```
/* n stands for the size of an image, sz stands for the patch size to extract */
int blockid3, blockid2, blockid;
for (k=0; k<=n[2]-sz[2]; k+=1) {
    blockid3 = k * (n[1]-sz[1]+1) * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (j=0; j<=n[1]-sz[1]; j+=1) {
        blockid2 = j * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);          // <--- here
        for (i=0; i<=n[0]-sz[0]; i+=1) {        // <--- here
            blockid = i + blockid2 + blockid3;  // <--- here

            /* copy single block */
            for (m=0; m<sz[2]; m++) {           // <--- here
                for (l=0; l<sz[1]; l++) {       // <--- and here
                    memcpy(b + blockid*sz[0]*sz[1]*sz[2] + m*sz[0]*sz[1] + l*sz[0], x+(k+m)*n[0]*n[1]+(j+l)*n[0]+i, sz[0]*sizeof(double));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

By the rules of OpenMP `blockid2`, `i`, `blockid`, `m`, and `l` are all implicitly shared which is not what you want. You should either make them `private`, or better declare them inside the parallel region and thus make them implicitly private:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,m,l,blockid,blockid2)
...
```

or

```
int blockid3;
for (k=0; k<=n[2]-sz[2]; k+=1) {
    blockid3 = k * (n[1]-sz[1]+1) * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (j=0; j<=n[1]-sz[1]; j+=1) {
        int blockid2 = j * (n[0]-sz[0]+1);
        for (int i=0; i<=n[0]-sz[0]; i+=1) {
            int blockid = i + blockid2 + blockid3;

            /* copy single block */
            for (int m=0; m<sz[2]; m++) {
                for (int l=0; l<sz[1]; l++) {
                    memcpy(b + blockid*sz[0]*sz[1]*sz[2] + m*sz[0]*sz[1] + l*sz[0], x+(k+m)*n[0]*n[1]+(j+l)*n[0]+i, sz[0]*sizeof(double));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The latter requires a C99-compliant compiler (because of the way loop variables are declared). Your GCC 4.6.3 requires the `-std=c99` option to enable C99 compliance. If no such compiler is available (are there still non-C99 compilers in general use?), you should add the `private(i,l,m)` clause. You might also want to move the parallelisation to the outermost loop instead in order to minimise the OpenMP overhead.

Comment: GCC and ICC both default to GNU89 which allows (with warning) mixed declarations (along with BCPL style comments).  GNU89 is better described as GNU99--.

Comment: GCC 4.8.2 with no `-std=c99` option: `c99.c:5:4: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`

Comment: When I do `int x; x=0; int i` I get `warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]` but when I do `for(int i=0; ...` it gives your error.  I guess mixed declarations are NOT the same as loop initial declarations.  This is super annoying!  I would much rather have loop initial declarations than mixed declarations.  What's the point in GNU89 allowing mixed declarations but not loop initial declarations?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when did the loop initial declaration appear for the first as a language construct in the C family.

Comment: In case you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229872/gnu89-mixed-declarations-and-loop-initial-declarations?noredirect=1#comment35540546_23229872

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks! This works. I forgot to check the race conditions.